# Noctua Fan not Responding to PWM Signal

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pwm

I recently got a Noctua Redux PWM fan and hooked it up to my Raspberry Pi and tried to control it via PWM signals.

I tried as many Python scripts online as I could find, modifying the frequency and changing the pin. My fan is hooked to GPIO 18 (pin 12) and I am using the following code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
PWM_FAN = 18
RPM = 0

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(PWM_FAN, GPIO.OUT)
fan = GPIO.PWM(PWM_FAN, 25000)
fan.start(0)
fan.ChangeDutyCycle(RPM/30)
if RPM == 0:
    fan.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

How can I get this code to control the fan correctly?

**EDIT:**
I tried controlling an LED with PWM and it fluctuated properly, but the fan still refuses to respond to PWM signals.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How do I get this code to control the fan correctly?

Comment: What does it actually do?  The code as you have it sets the speed to 0.

Comment: Right now the fan just turns on as soon as I plug it in to power. I'm trying to turn off the fan as I don't want it on 24/7 and then I'll turn it on when a specific event occurs.

Comment: The fan runs at full speed when there's no PWM signal, so I'd start by looking at the PWM output with a scope. Also, you chose 25KHz, so I assume that you've read this, but I'll link it anyway https://noctua.at/pub/media/wysiwyg/Noctua_PWM_specifications_white_paper.pdf 

You could also start smaller by trying to dim an LED.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try an LED tomorrow.

Comment: I tried an LED and it fluctuated properly, but the fan still refuses to respond to PWM signals. Should I try a normal Noctua Fan (not Redux)?